# In fragment, method doesn't appear on properties tab?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

My OneFragment.java code:

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment{
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    }

    public void gotofillhealth(View view){
        Intent gotofh = new Intent(getActivity(),HealthFragment.class);
        startActivity(gotofh);
    }
}
```

I can't select the method on Properties tab as OnClick event.

[image: CLICK FOR IMAGE]

I have tryed this code:

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent gotofh = new Intent(getActivity(),HealthFragment.class);
        startActivity(gotofh);
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to set the click listener on the desired view.

Comment: How, can you explain ?

Comment: add `android:onclick="onClick"` on your textView

Comment: I have added, now I get this error messages: http://i.hizliresim.com/o0abBk.png (Image)